# What is meant by Non Canonical Serialization?

Tags: python, json

I am sending an http request to a server, and it keeps throwing a 400 http error
with an error message of Non Canonical Serialization. I am trying to get my head around what this message means from what i've read up so far it sounds like it has something to do with my object keys not being sorted when I serialize it to JSON meaning the server doesn't get the same result each time I send the request I just wanted to know if this is along the right lines? Or is it something else totally?

Here is my code sending the request to the server:

```
def submit(mutation, pubkey, signature):


   headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}

   url = "http://192.168.99.100:8080/submit/"

   data = {
        "mutation": mutation,
        "signatures": [
               {
                 "pub_key": pubkey,
                 "signature": signature
                        }
                     ]
        }

   response = urllib2.Request(url, headers = { "Content-Type":  "application/json"}, data=json.dumps(data))

   f = urllib2.urlopen(response)

   print f
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `sort_keys=True` to `json.dumps`? And maybe `separators=(',',':')`? It's hard to tell exactly what the service you're working with is expecting, but sorting keys and dropping whitespace would be my first guess.

Comment: Yeh I tried sorting and using the separators initially but it still didn't work that's what made me think it might be something else